Using stunnel, how do I validate the certificate of a remote server
In order to log in to a remote server, I need to validate their certificate.  Using Stunnel, I have the following configuration file for the server:
client = no

accept = 127.0.0.1:9400
connect = 192.111.85.171:9400
cert = C:\Certificates\gain-futures-chain.pem
CAfile = C:\Certificates\gain-futures.pem
verifyChain = yes
verifyPeer = yes
checkHost = 192.111.85.171
checkIP = api.gainfutures.com
sslVersion = TLSv1.1
options = NO_SSLv2
options = NO_SSLv3
OCSPaia = yes
CAengine = pkcs11

Using this configuration, I receive the following log file output (only the relevant fields, since the stack overflow identifies this as "code" and I cannot post without reformatting):
024.07.15 08:54:21 LOG6[service]: Loading certificate from file: C:\Certificates\gain-futures-chain.pem

2024.07.15 08:54:21 LOG3[service]: error queue: ssl/ssl_rsa.c:472: error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib

2024.07.15 08:54:21 LOG3[service]: error queue: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:300: error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib

2024.07.15 08:54:21 LOG3[service]: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:297: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory

2024.07.15 08:54:21 LOG3[service]: Service [GainFuturesConnect]: Failed to initialize TLS context

2024.07.15 08:54:21 LOG3[service]: Configuration failed

I have downloaded the certificate from the remote server and used it within the configuration file.  My expectation is that I can log in to the service through the remote connection, but this consistently fails, and the log file confirms this, indicating that it is missing software modules to verify the remote certificate.
